# How can ı convert timestamp to datetime in Apache Nifi

Tags: datetime, apache-nifi

I want to convert timestamp to datetime.

Here is my JSON input :

```json
{
  "preMarket_timestamp": 1646830062,
  "regularMarket_timestamp": 1646773204,
  "earningsTimestamp": 1643301000,
  "earningsTimestampStart": 1651003200,
  "earningsTimestampEnd": 1651521600
}
```

The JSON result i want :

```json
{
  "preMarket_timestamp": "2022/03/09 16:09:26",
  "regularMarket_timestamp": "2022/03/09 00:00:04",
  "earningsTimestamp": "2022/01/27 19:30:00",
  "earningsTimestampStart": "2022/04/26 23:00:00",
  "earningsTimestampEnd": "2022/05/02 23:00:00"
}
```

Is there operation to do this convertion or can I do it with Nifi Expression Language?.Im stuck here.

It does not have to be separated with the "/" operator, it can also be "-".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **ScriptedTransformRecord** processor:

- `Record Reader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `Record Writer`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `Script Language`: `Groovy`
- `Script Body`:

```java
import org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.RecordField;
import org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.RecordFieldType;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

def formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul"))

record.setValue("preMarket_timestamp_formatted", formatter.format(new Date(record.getAsLong("preMarket_timestamp")*1000)))
record.setValue("regularMarket_timestamp_formatted", formatter.format(new Date(record.getAsLong("regularMarket_timestamp")*1000)))
record.setValue("earningsTimestamp_formatted", formatter.format(new Date(record.getAsLong("earningsTimestamp")*1000)))
record.setValue("earningsTimestampStart_formatted", formatter.format(new Date(record.getAsLong("earningsTimestampStart")*1000)))
record.setValue("earningsTimestampEnd_formatted", formatter.format(new Date(record.getAsLong("earningsTimestampEnd")*1000)))

return record
```

Output json:

```json
{
  "preMarket_timestamp" : 1646830062,
  "regularMarket_timestamp" : 1646773204,
  "earningsTimestamp" : 1643301000,
  "earningsTimestampStart" : 1651003200,
  "earningsTimestampEnd" : 1651521600,
  "preMarket_timestamp_formatted" : "2022/03/09 15:47:42",
  "regularMarket_timestamp_formatted" : "2022/03/09 00:00:04",
  "earningsTimestamp_formatted" : "2022/01/27 19:30:00",
  "earningsTimestampStart_formatted" : "2022/04/26 23:00:00",
  "earningsTimestampEnd_formatted" : "2022/05/02 23:00:00"
}
```